# Firebase 9.6.6 JS from CDN errors out

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to hook CDN based firebase libs for one of my project and as per the doc its doable
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup

But when i put below html/js code

```
<html>
<body>
  <script type="module">
    import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js'
    // Add Firebase products that you want to use
    import { auth } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-auth.js'
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "<>",
        authDomain: "<>.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "<>",
        storageBucket: "<>.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "<>",
        appId: "<>",
        measurementId: "<>"
   };
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Its error out with below log (seen on console)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: auth
```

I do not want to fallback to older version of firebase, so is there any solution someone can suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing the modular SDK, which does not export an `auth` symbol. To get access to the auth service, import the `getAuth` function:

```
import { getAuth } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-auth.js'
```

And then call it as:

```
const auth = getAuth();

// And then for example: createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
```

I recommend keeping the Firebase documentation on [getting started with authentication on the web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start) handy while getting started, as it has handy copy/pasteable code snippets for common operations like this.

Comment: Can you share any working example? I see "SyntaxError: redeclaration of import auth" when used code shared by you.

Comment: That should've been `getAuth` in the `import`, so I just updated that. Give it another try.